# ¿Por que mis estilos no están funcionado en mi master page en aspx?

Tags: c#, .net, aspx

Actualmente tengo un sitio web y dicho sitio web contiene elementos referenciados repetitivos que se usan en diversas paginas de la aplicación, para eso quiero usar una master page.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebSite.master.cs" Inherits="WebSite" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
        <link href="Content/boostrap.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" />
        <link href="Content/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server"/>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="body" runat="server">
    <label>Funciona</label>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</body>
</html>
```

Ni los links me traen la información de los archivos y el label no me imprime lo que le puse, si son las direcciones correctas porque si lo pongo en el archivo directo si funciona y están al mismo nivel de folders el master y el archivo aspx.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" MasterPageFile="~/WebSite.master" %>


<asp:Content ID="IdHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <title>Gestion de Certificaciones</title>
    <%--    <link href="Content/boostrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /--%>
    <link href="Content/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/Login.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Multimedia/img/isban_cube.ico" />    
    <link href="Plugins/SweetAlert2/SweetAlert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Plugins/SweetAlert2/SweetAlert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>

        function alertErros(ex) {
            swal({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Problemas',
                text: ex,
                footer: '<a href>porfavor, cierre esta ventana.</a>'
            })
        }

    </script>

</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">

<div class="wrapper">
    <form runat="server" id="frmLogin" class="login" defaultbutton="btnLogin">
        <p class="title"><asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgLogo" ImageUrl="Multimedia/img/isban_cube_sm.png" ImageAlign="AbsBottom"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gestion de Certificaciones</p>
        <span><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUserName" Text="Usuario" AssociatedControlID="txtUserName" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUserName" placeholder="" style="text-transform:uppercase;"/>
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        <span><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPassword" Text="Contraseña" AssociatedControlID="txtPassword" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" />
            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMsg" Text="" CssClass="labelMsg"></asp:Label>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="ReturnUrl" Value="Default.aspx" />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnLogin" CssClass="button" OnClientClick="return validateEnter();" OnClick="btnLogin_OnClick" >
            <i class="spinner"></i>
            <span class="state">ENTRAR</span>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </form>
</div>


<script>

    function validateEnter() {
        var user = $("#txtUserName").val();
        var pass = $("#txtPassword").val();
        if (user == "" || pass == "") {
            alertErros("Debe rellenar los campos de inicio de sesion");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

</script>

</asp:Content>
```

También use lo siguiente:

```
    <link href="~/Content/boostrap.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" />
    <link href="~/Content/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar que te muestra la consola de Chrome?
Aparte, la carpeta que contiene tus estilos es Publica?, puedes revisarlo en el webconfig, si no lo es ese puede ser el problema.

Comment: @Elcainas la consola de los navegadores sale limpia y no encuentro ninguna carpeta en el webconfig

Answer (score 0):

Ya probaste algo así?

```
<link href="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Content/boostrap.css") %>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Ojala te funcione, saludos.

> La URL que devuelve este método es relativa a la carpeta que contiene
>   el archivo de origen en el que se crea una instancia del control. Los
>   controles que heredan esta propiedad, como UserControl y MasterPage ,
>   devolverán una URL completa en relación con el control.

[Referencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: ya lo intenten y me salio el siguiente error:  "Las etiquetas de servidor no pueden contener construcciones <% ... %>".

Answer (score 0):

tienes mal entendido el funcionamiento del master, el contenido del master va afuera de los `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` y el contenido de los hijos dentro del `asp:content`, por eso no renderizas ni label ni los links.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/boostrap.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" />
    <link href="Content/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server"/>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="body" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<label>Funciona</label>
</body>
</html>
```